# What versions of the C++ standard library can I use within AWA Lambda?

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-cpp

Aws Lambda is supporting C++ since late 2018 ([official announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-the-c-lambda-runtime/)). I would like to know which versions of the C++ standard library I can use AWS Lambda. Could you point me to an official AWS document?

Why I am asking this: I recently switched from C++ 11 to C++ 17 and have issues now. I suspect it might be the C++ version.

Sidenote: The example in the post above is using C++ 11.

Comment: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-cpp this github repo says the supported compilers are any c++11 compliant. So that may be the reason.

Comment: Oops. Corrected @Scheff

Comment: @Hemil I looked at the main page of the sdk again. According to that, c++ 11 OR LATER is supported. https://sdk.amazonaws.com/cpp/api/LATEST/index.html

Comment: If I am using C++ 17, what do I have to pay attention to? Do I have to compile it in a specific way? Do I have to recompile the SDK in C++17?

Comment: I don't know buddy. Sorry. I am a teen not an AWS expert. I just googled it.

Comment: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-cpp#packaging-abi-gnu-c-library-oh-my is probably worth a read. You'll need to supply a [mre] for further help

Comment: @AlanBirtles Agree. I am doing exactly that